# JEE : POI and docx work fine from IDE, not from generated WAR

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working with docx files.

When I run my web application from my IDE (intellij), these instructions work fine:

```
private static void appendBody(CTBody src, CTBody append) throws Exception {
    XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
    optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
    String appendString = append.xmlText(optionsOuter);
    String srcString = src.xmlText();
    String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
    String mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    String suffix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
    String addPart = appendString.substring(appendString.indexOf(">") + 1, appendString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
    src.set(makeBody);
}
```

But when I run the generated war (generated with **mvn -Pprod package**), I am getting an error at the line :

```
CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
```

Error :

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Use of undefined namespace prefix: w15
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3499)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:713)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:697)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:684)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:80)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I don't understand why it works when ran from the IDE and not with the generated WAR.

Comment: are you reading the same file in both cases? the exception indicates XML parsing issues that could be caused by corrupt XML in the docx file

Comment: it was a conflict in some dependencies in the pom. Strange thing is that it wasn't a problem for Intellij, but when I was running the war then it was a problem.